# I want to sort the object numbers in order

Tags: objects

I deleted a few objects while working, and the order of the objects was messed up. So I want to arrange the names of all the objects in order. How do I do this?[image]

In this photo, I want to arrange numbers 2729 and then 1877 in order.

Comment: In order? Do you mean 2729 would be 1877 in the example above?

Comment: You want to sort by inverse alphabetical order ?

Comment: Do you mean "rename" the objects so they are numbered sequentially with no gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below will rename all objects in the scene, so:

- First having a base name before '.' is named from this base name (example "Cube")
- Next with the base name + their rank after the first one (example "Cube.rank")

Comments below for key points:

```
import bpy


objects = bpy.context.scene.collection.all_objects

prev_base = ""
index = 0
sep = "."

for name in sorted(o.name for o in objects):
    #Get the base name
    splitted = name.rsplit(sep, 1)
    base = splitted[0]
    #If the base name has changed
    if base != prev_base:
        #Keep a new base
        prev_base = base
        #Rename the object
        objects[name].name = base
        #Restart to 0
        index = 0
    else:
        #Next index
        index += 1
        #Assign formatted name
        objects[name].name = base + "." + str(index).zfill(3)
```